# Automatically cc myself when sending from 1 particular email account - OSX mail

Tags: mail.app, email, gmail, imap

I've got multiple email accounts in OSX Mail, a mixture of gmail, google apps mail, and me.com ... all of which are connecting via imap / smtp.

With one of the accounts I want to automatically cc a copy of all outgoing emails to another email address.

What's the best way to do this? I can see there is a auto cc myself option under the composing tab in preferences, but this would seem to auto cc emails sent from every email account, rather than just 1 particular account.

System : OSX 10.10

Comment: You're probably going to have to use a third-party utility, e.g. [Mail Act-On](https://smallcubed.com/mao/) "_Outbox rules give you the power to alter and organize the messages you send. With Act-On you can automatically CC or BCC messages depending on rule criteria._"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this isn't possible with the built-in  Mail rule set in Yosemite. As mentioned by user3439894, you have to rely on a third-party utility. Here’s a screenshot from [Mail Act-on](https://smallcubed.com/mao/) site.

[image]
You can build your own rule using the additional third-party rule set e.g. Add CC Recipient. So people we see that you have added them to Cc list.

Comment: Thanks although this will send a copy to another email address, it wouldnt be a cc'ed version, part of what i want to do here is enable the recipient to also see that the message was cc'ed to another person

Comment: I have edited my previous answer.